# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token - Can't find invisible character

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, syntax

Keep getting this error. I've checked for hidden characters, deleted and retyped lines, etc. to no avail. Any ideas where this hidden character might be? I'm using almost identical code in another file which is working perfectly. Thanks!

```
$('#register-manager').validate({
        rules:{
            company-company_name: {
            required: true
        },
        user-first_name: {
            required: true
        },
         user-last_name: {
            required: true
        },
         user-email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
         user-password1: {
            required: true,
            min: 8
        },
         user-password2: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
         company-company_name: {
            required: "Please enter your company's name."
        },
         user-first_name: {
            required: "Please enter your first name."
        },
        user-last_name: {
            required: "Please enter your last name."
        },
         user-email: {
            required: "Please enter your email.",
            email: "Please enter a valid email."
        },
         user-password1: {
            required: "Please enter your password.",
            min: "Please enter at least 8 characters."
        },
         user-password2: {
            required: "Please verify your password."
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) { 
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no hidden characters (as far as I can tell). The problem is right there in the error message:

> Unexpected token `-`

Identifiers in JS cannot contain `-` characters, try wrapping them in quotes like this:

```
$('#register-manager').validate({
    rules:{
        "company-company_name": {
        required: true
    },
    "user-first_name": {
        required: true
    },
    ...
```

Comment: @alexj -It happens to the best of us. Happy coding.